# mixin whose super class is not Object

Tags: dart

i want to do something like the following so bad

```
abstract class A{}                      
abstract class B extends A{}
abstract class C extends A{}
abstract class D extends B with C{} //C cannot be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than object
```

is there any solution other than copying the content of C in D?

the real names of my classes, to give you an idea of what i am trying to do

```
//A Observable
//B DynamicObservable
//C ObservableWithValidationErrors
//D DynamicObservableWithValidationErrors
```

Comment: It's impossible to do what you want currently, but maybe a concrete example of why you want this would expose a suitable workaround for your situation?

Comment: @PixelElephant added the real class names to give you an idea, none has a constructor just shared functionality

Comment: Could you extract the functionality into another mixin, or does it strictly rely on inheritance? For instance, classes: Observable, Dynamic, DynamicObservable extends Observable with Dynamic.

Comment: @PixelElephant i am doing something like that but i was hoping for full mixin support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some restrictions on the class you can use as mixin (See [Mixins in Dart - Syntax and semantics](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/mixins/#syntax-and-semantics)).

> However, in this proposal, a mixin may only be extracted from a class that obeys the following restrictions:
>
> 1. The class has no declared constructors.
> 2. The class’ superclass is Object.
> 3. The class contains no super calls.

Those restrictions may be removed in the future.

> The semantics are deliberately restricted in several ways, so as to reduce disruption to our existing implementations, while allowing future evolution toward a full-fledged mixin implementation. This restricted version already provides considerable value.

Comment: two years later and are still with this issue. My problem is that I need to use source_gen generators like Serializable and still extend some other classes. What to do in this case?

Answer (score 2):

In some circumstances it might be possible to restructure your class to use multiple mixins instead:

```dart
abstract class Observable{}
abstract class Dynamic{}
abstract class ValidationErrors{}        
abstract class DynamicObservable extends Observable with Dynamic{}
abstract class ObservableWithValidationErrors extends Observable with ValidationErrors{}
abstract class DynamicObservableWithValidationErrors extends Observable with Dynamic, ValidationErrors{}
```

Of course, if `Dynamic` or `ValidationErrors` cannot be isolated this way, and rely on inheriting from `Observable`, this will not be possible.